# Update new dba credential in batch file

Tags: file, batch-file

how to update DB batch file in database  with new dba credential and delete the previous Dba details. please help .

Comment: Did you tried it yourself before? Share your code as we can point out where you did wrong.

Comment: no i didnt try.. i want to know the process.